# Как указать nuget кастомный путь до dll файлов?

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, tfs

Есть проект на .NET Standard 2.0.
Собираю nuget пакеты на TFS. Но nuget почему-то все время пытается искать dll в стандартной директории "bin\release\MyProject\bin\release\" как ему указать правильный путь до dll?

Текущая команда для сборки пакета:

`\\share\nuget.exe pack "e:\b\Agent2\11\s\Src\MyProject\MyProject.csproj" -OutputDirectory "e:\b\Agent2\11\b" -Properties Configuration=release;OutDir="e:\b\Agent2\11\b" -IncludeReferencedProjects  -version 1.0.0.679929 -BasePath "e:\b\Agent2\11\b"`

Dll после билда кладутся в "e:\b\Agent2\11\b" но при выполнении команды получаю ошибку:

`Unable to find 'bin\release\MyProject\bin\release\'. Make sure the project has been built.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем после просмотров исходников NuGet, чтобы исправить эту ошибку нужно добавить TargetPath в Properties

`-Properties Configuration=release;OutDir="e:\b\Agent2\11\b";TargetPath="e:\b\Agent2\11\b"`

Но это все равно приводит к ошибкам, так как оказалось, что NuGet не поддерживает .Net Core

Для того чтобы собрать пакет .Net Core нужно:

- Вариант 1. Добавить опцию в .csproj
  `<GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>`

  В этом случае пакет будет генерироваться при каждой сборке
- Вариант 2. Использовать команду:

  `dotnet pack`

  https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-pack?tabs=netcore2x